# Power Apps Portal - div id tag disappears after saving

Tags: html, powerapps, portal

I have added a div to a page in a Power Apps Portal with something similar to this bit of code.

```
<div id="123" style="width: 400px; height: 70%; background: red;"></div>
```

However, I'm not sure what's triggering it, but every time after I save, at some point just the `id="123"` part disappears from the code. It's especially problematic because the portal will save on its own, removing that ID property.

What is causing this to happen, and how can I prevent it from happening?

Comment: What kind of page, and what else is on the page; an entity form, list, web form? Do you have other JS included on the page or associated elements?